# Determine the Ports reserved and what service reserved them in Windows XP/2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-xp, tcp, port, udp

this question is always rise.
How can i know what ports are currently reserved in windows XP/2003 and what service had reserved them.

for example when i want to install Apache, default port will be 80, but sometimes the Server will have IIS installed on the same port.

so i want to know the way to check the ports and what services had reserved them and also if there is a way to re assign those ports to different services.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try [PortQry](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=832919) and see if this helps you find what you're after.

Comment: thanks, but it didint help so much. i have apache at port 80 and i have tomcat at port 8080 but it didnt list them in the reserved ports

Comment: it worked, but is there a way to stop a service from using a port and then assign that port to another service?

Comment: also, it displays the general Services, for example port 80 is for HTTP but it didnt specify which unit or service is occupy it ( IIS or apache or another one ) is there any way to accomplish this ?

Comment: From what I see it links the port to the process id so you can run a query and match up what you're looking for from the output.  I haven't used it a lot, just thought it might find what you were looking for.